# Create data-frame with specific number of rows with R

Tags: json, r, csv, dplyr

I have a large json file which size is more then 2GB. As data size is very large I cannot create data-frame with whole data set. I want parse specific info and write into a CSV file.

So I am looking for some technique to create data-frame with specific number of rows.

Suppose I have 2M rows when I parse my json to data-frame, I want to create a data-frame with only **10k-15k** rows per process. And then write some info into a CSV file.

Each process will have **10k-15k** rows until it finish all 2M rows.

I am working with **tidyjson** and **dplyr** package.

Comment: How about splitting the HUGE json file to smaller ones outside of R?

Comment: Can you show us, what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to do splitting of the big file to smaller ones and go parallel with:

```
 library(parallel)
 json_files<-list.files(path = "path/to/jsons",pattern="*.json",full.names = TRUE)#get the files' location

 no_cores <- detectCores() - 1
 registerDoParallel(cores=no_cores)  
 cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)

system.time(json_list<-parLapply(cl,json_files,function(x) rjson::fromJSON(file=x,method = "R")))

  stopCluster(cl)#Once we are done we need to close the cluster so that resources such as memory are returned to the operating system.
  gc()#just a garbage collection call.
```

You now have a list that holds the whole *imported* information.